# Key Error: value not in index ..... but it is there

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

Python

I'm trying to use the below code to make a new dataframe:

```
new = old[['x', 'y', 'z']]
```

When I print the old dataframe, it shows me the column value 'x' for that column. In other parts of my program, I'm able to call the value 'x' to use that column's information in various things. For reasons I and the internet cannot fathom, I'm getting a KeyError for 'x' in this line of code.

(PS PyCharm even tries to be helpful and fill in the 'x' value when I begin to type the actual name in this code. It recognizes that it's there.)

*EDIT* SOLUTION:
When I used set_index earlier it did something to mess up the ability to read by the x label.

```
    old = pd.read_csv("name.csv")
    old['a'] = old['a'].str.replace(",", "")
    old['a'] = old['a'].str.replace(" ", "_")
    old['x'] = old['x'].str.replace(" ", "_")
    old.drop(["b", "c", "d"], axis=1, inplace=True)
    old = old.set_index("x")
```

Comment: Provide us with what you've tried along with code so we can inspect and help

Comment: How much more code do you need? So far I have 98 lines with plots and functions unrelated to this current problem. The only thing I can think to add is the initial dataframe creation code but I'm not sure how useful that will be without the data. I will add that above.

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT: When looking at the additional code I had the realization (after a night of sleep) that the set_index code (see above addition) is what threw it off. Thanks for asking me to include more code because that was the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to access 'x' you would need to write:
new[0][0]